# Delayed shooting not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to implement the delayed shooting effect in my space shooter. I found the code on unity docs, and found the same code on other places. But when I do it, it just does not seems to work. What am I doing wrong? here's the code:

```cs
public float fireRate = 0.25f;
public float nextFire = 0.0f;
// .........
if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time > nextFire)
{
    Instantiate(shot, shotSpawn.position, shotSpawn.rotation);
    nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
}
```

Whatever value put into fireRate, there's no delay between fire. What's wrong?

Comment: you wrote `Unity3D` and set `unity` tag

Comment: What happens if you increase the initial value of `fireRate` to something like `5f`?

Comment: Can it be that you have set the value `fireRate` in the editor? The editor will overwrite any value set in code when initializing.

Comment: @JohanLindkvist's point is good, maybe remove public to make sure you are using the scripted values. Also have you tried increasing the `fireRate` by a large amount? It could be just be too small to notice.

Comment: Prolly won't fix this but you can get rid of a variable and some lines if you just do `Time.time % fireRate == 0`

Answer (score 0):

Code is perfectly fine, maybe values messed up in Inspector? They override values set in scripts.

Comment: Thanks guys for the replies. For the first time i noticed this. The editor's value of fireRate was 0, and i entirely ran the program with the code (i didn't touched the editor). But now when you guys suggested, i entered the value 5 via editor, and it worked. But i want to control this with the code. How can i prevent the editor overriding my code values??

Comment: don't make it public, or use `[HideInInspector]`

Comment: Another alternative is to use `[NonSerialized]`, which keeps a variable at the value specified in code - which I think may be more desirable than `[HideInInspector]`, as the latter will still retain a serialized value if you've already set one in the inspector before hiding it. [Worth a read](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/199691/nonserialized-vs-hideininspector-question.html).

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. :)